# Which CPU configuration should I use for my Windows CE 60 device?

Tags: c++, configuration, windows-mobile, embedded, windows-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why simple console app runs but dialog based does not run in WIN CE 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959134/why-simple-console-app-runs-but-dialog-based-does-not-run-in-win-ce-6-0)

My device is [iPA280](http://www.ingenico.com/en/ipa280/features/technical-specifications_gjya99uj.html). It has:

**Main Processor:** Marvell PXA-300 (XScale ARM) @ 624 MHz

**Operating System:** WinCE 6 pro

I am developing an application in embedded Visual C++ 4 with service pack 4 for this device. Which configuration (ARMV4, ARMV4I, MIPSII and...) should I use for building correct .EXE file for this device?

I have tested most of configurations but my application only works in emulator correctly and .exe files in other configurations do not work on device. some of .exe files has invalid EXE message and some do not run without any message or error or warning.

Thanks,

Comment: That's an XScale chipset, and they're strictly ARMv5; it's quite likely that VC++ 4.0 was released before ARMv5 was. Do you have a further question, or does that answer it (and WTF are you using such an old compiler)?

Comment: Which of these configurations in Embedded Visual C++ is that?

`armV4,
armV4i,
armV4t,
mips16,
mipsII,
mipsII_fp,
mipsIV,
mipsIV_fp,
sh3,
sh4,
x86`

Comment: None -- your compiler was made before the chipset was. :-]

Comment: What should I do now? Do you know any solution?

Comment: Upgrade to a compiler made in the last 15 years?

Comment: We need some dll files. I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965480/779408).

Answer (score 4):

ARM v5 is backwards compatible with the ARMv4 instruction set, so I don't think the problem lies here. The program may fail to start on actual device for a variety of other reasons.

1. You may be linking to lib that is non-existent on device, for example aygshell.dll or ccrtrtti.lib
2. You may be exporting function ordinal not present in core.dll of this windows build (try ExecutabilityCheck.exe for this; this free little program will tell which functions are missing http://www.hpcfactor.com/downloads/details.asp?r=40A26F4C-E4AC-41C9-81A1-1D81B4C41A0E)
3. Check linker command line, for one old project that I was involved in, and it worked ok on windows mobile 4 up to 6.5 I've had this "/subsystem:windowsce,4.02 /machine:ARM"

Comment: can you look at [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10959134/779408)? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ARM v4 will generate code that will run, but you may hit problems with the SDK you use, and further problems when you come to debug.  I'd recommend moving to Visual Studio 2008.  (Not VS2010 because it doesn't include native Windows mobile development).